# How to correctly interpret output of vacuum progress command? select * from svv_vacuum_progress;

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm running command `select * from svv_vacuum_progress`; and RedShift responds with following in `status` column `Vacuum select count(blocknum) from stv_blocklist`. The `time_remaining_estimate` column has `null` value.

My question is what does status `Vacuum select count(blocknum) from stv_blocklist` really mean. I can't find my documentation on this status.

Answer (score 5):

I found this view (**svv_vacuum_progress**) to be somehow unrealiable. Sometimes the status shows **Complete**, which is great, but sometimes it shows something else, even though the vacuum has finished. It seems to depend on the time it takes to do the vacuum, but don't rely on this statement. The documentation currently is quite poor as well.

If your use case is similar to mine (even though you're not asking specifically about this) - check if there is a vacuum currently running and if not, run it - then you can probably use the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM stv_recents
WHERE status = 'Running' AND query ILIKE '%VACUUM%';
```

You can modify your query according to your own requirements, of course. I hope this helps you or someone else!

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the last table that was vacuumed was the `stv_blocklist` and it's currently not being vacuumed.

[Here is the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_VACUUM_PROGRESS.html), you can see the sample outputs on the bottom.

Comment: None of the examples show `select count(blocknum) from stv_blocklist` as value of status column.

Comment: Ya, they don't give all the status examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably use sql queries to check the progress of a vacuum, because the process appears as complete several times during the operation. It maybe has to stop between steps.

The best solution I've found for this so far is running a vacuum with the verbose option and looking at the redshift console, in the queries tab.
There, you will have a more detailed view of what's happening with your vacuum